# How can I build a single file .ts to my src? by setting up the tsconfig.js (command yarn build)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDirs": [
      "./components",
      "./pages",
      "./public",
      "./styles",
      "./utils",
      "./types",
      "./services"
    ],
    "outDir": "./src",
    },
    "include": [
     "next-env.d.ts",
     "**/*.ts",
     "**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
     "node_modules",
     "lib"
    ],
    "types": [
     "cypress",
     "@percy/cypress"
    ]
    },
```

I want to make this project a library that will embed the intercom button on any website. My senior suggested I build a single .ts file that includes all of my code in the src folder through yarn build, but I am still unable to do so. This project is written using NextJS and Typescript. Any suggestion? The following is the sample directory of the project.

```
project
| components
  | component 1
    | some .ts & .tsx files // including styles.ts file and index.ts
  | component 2
    | same structure as comp 1
  | index.ts // for exporting
| pages
  | API
    | some .ts files
  | _app.tsx & other .tsx files
| public
  | font
  | some icons & image folder
| service
  | folder
    | config.ts
| styles
  | theme.ts, styles.ts, .css
| types
  | some .d.ts & .ts & folder
| utils
  | some .ts & folder that contained functions used in this project.
| src
```

Answer (score 0):

You might follow T3's documentation about their folder structure. Basically, the `src` folder contains all other folders such as `pages`, `styles`, `utils` , ...

```
.
├─ public
│  └─ favicon.ico
├─ prisma
│  └─ schema.prisma
├─ src
│  ├─ env.mjs
│  ├─ pages
│  │  ├─ _app.tsx
│  │  ├─ api
│  │  │  ├─ auth
│  │  │  │  └─ [...nextauth].ts
│  │  │  └─ trpc
│  │  │     └─ [trpc].ts
│  │  └─ index.tsx
│  ├─ server
│  │  ├─ auth.ts
│  │  ├─ db.ts
│  │  └─ api
│  │     ├─ routers
│  │     │  └─ example.ts
│  │     ├─ trpc.ts
│  │     └─ root.ts
│  ├─ styles
│  │  └─ globals.css
│  └─ utils
│     └─ api.ts
├─ .env
├─ .env.example
├─ .eslintrc.cjs
├─ .gitignore
├─ next-env.d.ts
├─ next.config.mjs
├─ package.json
├─ postcss.config.cjs
├─ prettier.config.cjs
├─ README.md
├─ tailwind.config.ts
└─ tsconfig.json
```

More information here: https://create.t3.gg/en/folder-structure

Upvote would be highly appreciated if you found this helpful! Thanks!!